# How to add a polygon in Google Earth on a Website

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, google-earth, html5, google-earth-api

As it is said in the title i have to add a polygon in Google Earth which is integrated in a website.
I managed to integrate Google Earth in the Website, so i can view the world but i can not use any functions like searching specific places or add paths. Does anybody know what i could do to fix this? Or did i used a wrong method to integrate Google Earth?
I hope this is the right question for this forum.

Ps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking to do is draw a polygon onto the map using a series of coordinates for the inside and outside bounds. If you want a solid filled polygon, do not include the points for the inner shape. The following code would produce a polygon with a missing center. There are comments within to the code to help guide you as well. I hope this is what you're looking for.

```
// Create the placemark.
var polygonPlacemark = ge.createPlacemark('');

// Create the polygon.
var polygon = ge.createPolygon('');
polygon.setAltitudeMode(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
polygonPlacemark.setGeometry(polygon);

// Add points for the outer shape.
var outer = ge.createLinearRing('');
outer.setAltitudeMode(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
outer.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(48.80, -121.80, 700);
outer.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(48.80, -121.90, 700);
outer.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(48.70, -121.90, 700);
outer.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(48.70, -121.80, 700);
polygon.setOuterBoundary(outer);

// Add inner points.
var inner = ge.createLinearRing('');
inner.setAltitudeMode(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
inner.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(48.77, -121.83, 700);
inner.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(48.77, -121.87, 700);
inner.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(48.73, -121.87, 700);
inner.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(48.73, -121.83, 700);
polygon.getInnerBoundaries().appendChild(inner);

//Create a style and set width and color of line
polygonPlacemark.setStyleSelector(ge.createStyle(''));
var lineStyle = polygonPlacemark.getStyleSelector().getLineStyle();
lineStyle.setWidth(5);
lineStyle.getColor().set('9900ffff');

// Add the placemark to Earth.
ge.getFeatures().appendChild(polygonPlacemark);
```

More information can be found on [Google Earth for Developers, Geometries and Overlays](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/geometries).

Comment: Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: If it got you to a solution that works for you will you please accept the answer so others can see that the answer has been provided. Thanks!

Comment: For sure i am new here i didnt knew that.

Comment: @Avanger12 I would suggest carefully looking through the [tour] for further guidance on how the site operates. Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange!